# Chrome Extension that allows copying of text from MKS Integrity

Tags: software-development, chrome, software-testing

Currently, I am using [MKS Integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTC_Integrity) for issue/system lifecycle management and my main browser for personal use is Chrome. On MKS, the text on any ticket/issue isn't selectable or copyable.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an extension that would allow for the text to be selectable or copyable. Currently, a workaround is to inspect the text in the developer tools, and copy it from there, but I would prefer for it to work like a normal site.

For a reference, the version is 2009 (if there are any differences between versions/extensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice extension for chrome called [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) which allows you to put in custom CSS that only apply for certain domains.

Using Stylish, I just added the following for MKS:

```
div {
        user-select: text !important;
        -webkit-user-select: text !important;
    }
```